# Taking the Double integral?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let D be the (rotated) square in R^2 with vertices (+/- 1,0) and (0,+/-1). Let f(x,y) = 5, g(x,y) = xy, and h(x,y)= y^2. Compute the double integrals of f(x,y), g(x,y), and h(x,y)

This question is confusing me a bit. What does it mean by a rotated square? Can someone explain what this question is asking of me? Thanks.

Comment: Try plotting the $4$ points and connecting the dots. You should have a square (though it will look like a diamond with the axes in their normal orientation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's calculate the integral over D for h(x,y) = y^2. Note D is made of 4 small triangles that have equal area. So we only need to calculate the integral of h over the region bounded by the triangle in the 1st quadrant. Its equation is: x + y = 1, and  x, y non-negative.

So Int(x = 0 to 1)Int(y = 0 to 1 - x)y^2dydx = Int(x = 0 to 1)(1 - x)^3/3dx = 1/12. So the 3rd  integral for h = 4*1/12 = 1/3.

Comment: Why do you have to just have to look at the region in the first quadrant?